# How do you access script on your ActionScript class from inside a movie-clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I want to be able to access a private var from inside a movieclip, does anyone know how I would go about doing that?

I want to be able to access my `public function counter(numPoints:int)` that is inside the ActionScript class file from inside a movieclip on my main swf. Whenever I try to access it, it comes up as undefined, but how to access it from inside the movieclip is the problem(I know the variables are all defined properly because it works when it isn't inside of a movieclip). Any idea are appreciated ^^;, Thanks!

```
      unlock3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_3);

    function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(8);
        addScore(1);
}
```

I want to make it so the addScore function works properly, but it always comes out undefined. This script here is inside of the movieclip. The navigation works fine, but I don't know how to target the score.

Comment: You need to put up some code to describe the issue more clearly.

Comment: I added the code, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's still unclear what exactly you are doing, your function is named counter but you are calling addScore. See if this helps.

In your document class (lets assume it is called Main) you would have something like:

```
private var _currentScore:int;

public function addScore(scoreToAdd:int):void
{

_currentScore += scoreToAdd;

trace("New Score: "+_currentScore);

}
```

Then within your object class which extends MovieClip you would have:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
Main.addScore(1);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but i got "Call to a possibly undefined method addScore through a reference with a static type Class." 'public function addScore(numPoints:int)' was the one I meant to paste in my original post. Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to teach myself actionscript and I am sort of new, so I can't quite get it to work. I am trying to get a movieclip inside of a movieclip to give navigation- which is set-up already, but also to addScore, but the addScore function is in Actionscript class file rather than on the main project. I hope that explains it better.

Comment: It's still very difficult to see your exact problem without seeing an example. Perhaps you could zip up a few files?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?v56ikz0y7sx06dz
Go to FLA file and simply go to debug and it should bring you to what i am talking about. I want the function addScore to work from that location- or make it so by clicking on that movieclip, the function goes off.

Comment: Can't download that. It says file is blocked for violating terms?

Comment: It let me download just fine, that is odd. Do you have a preferred website you would like to download it from or something?

Comment: I could also email it to you directly if you are comfortable with that.